# Why are ID questions not removed immediately?

Tags: discussion, scope, identify, deleted-questions

Since ID questions are off-topic, why are the moderators not removing ID questions immediately right after a user posts them?

This [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/111694/i-have-been-trying-to-find-this-movie-for-years-it-is-a-movie-about-the-holocau) has been asked 16 hours ago but it's still online.

Comment: It was closed 3 minutes after opening. On Stack Exchange sites, questions aren't immediately deleted unless the content is troubling in some way.

Comment: While asking from the opposite viewpoint, the answers to [this related question](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4229/49) seem to pretty much apply here, too. I.e. as Glorfindel points out there's usually not a pressing need to delete them immediately as long as they're closed. But likewise is there no reason to keep them alive once closed, other than possibly avoiding confusion of new users. But since this confusion has been clarified in other venues, it can as well be deleted now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They will automatically be removed after 9 days, provided that they are closed and don't have a positive score. There's an automated process for this nicknamed [Roomba](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/roomba), no need to bother the ♦ moderators with this; it's not like the questions are harmful. They just won't be answered. Also, if the question's score is -4 or lower, [it will not appear on the homepage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138382/295232), only on the other question lists, so most users won't be bothered by them.

Comment: And once a question is at -3 and closed, users with enough rep can click on the "delete" link at the bottom and nominate the question for deletion. Once two users have done so, the question is deleted (Which is what happened with this question).

Comment: @BCdotWEB I think it actually needs three users, unless one of them is a moderator, which is what happened with this question as explained in the other comment.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Ah, that's the case, I thought that the third vote was an automatic one.